# Can't find encoding for more than one language in NSData (iPhone SDK)?

Tags: iphone, encoding, json

I have been trying to find encoding for below json strings from a day.
I am getting jSon string like

```
[
  {
    "ParentId": "154",
    "TopMenuId": "159",
    "MainMenuText": "开放时间",
    "Language": "6",
    "MenuImage": ""
  },
  {
    "ParentId": "154",
    "TopMenuId": "166",
    "MainMenuText": "СЕРТИФИКАЦИЯ ISO",
    "Language": "8",
    "MenuImage": ""
  }
]
```

with browser it looks ok. but when i get NSData String Encoding in NSLog it shows,

```
[
  {
    "ParentId": "154",
    "TopMenuId": "159",
    "MainMenuText": "&#24320;&#25918;&#26102;&#38388;",
    "Language": "6",
    "MenuImage": ""
  },
  {
    "ParentId": "154",
    "TopMenuId": "166",
    "MainMenuText": "&#1057;&#1045;&#1056;&#1058;&#1048;&#1060;&#1048;&#1050;&#1040;&#1062;&#1048;&#1071; ISO",
    "Language": "8",
    "MenuImage": ""
  }
]
```

I used almost all CFString Encoding but still do not get success.

**Note:** When i put NSLog in Browser it looks OK. but when it stores it in xcdatamodeld with string it store as &#1057 format.

please help me..
Thanks, in advance.

Comment: Those are HTML entities. The browser renders them, the NSLog doesn't. Where are they coming from and why are they HTML entity encoded?

Comment: Thanks deceze,sorry.. I don't get what do you mean? contain comes from URL, return in json string. I also tried without any encoding but then also it displays in NSLog & Database in &#1040  format.

Comment: Who is *encoding* this data?!

Comment: without any encoding means,NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:nil];

Comment: @Ruchi If you can please change the response in the server.....\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, there are two different kinds of encoding we're talking about here. Any string is first and foremost encoded as *byte sequence*. I.e. the string "bits" is encoded as these bits in the ASCII encoding:

```
01100010 01101001 01110100 01110011
```

That's the kind of encoding we're talking about in code like:

```
[[NSString alloc] initWithData:... encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
```

But that's not the problem you have. Your string is encoded in ASCII, but the characters in it are not represented as their actual characters, but as XML/HTML entities. I.e. instead of the letter `С` encoded in UTF-8, you have the HTML entity `&#1057;`, the byte encoding of which is pretty irrelevant.

You need to either HTML-entity-decode those characters, or not HTML encode them to begin with before sending them. Having HTML entity representations of characters in a JSON string is pretty unusual and superfluous.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't tell you the Cocoa method to HTML entity decode something, but a search through the documentation should yield results pretty easily. I would suggest to fix the problem at the source though, by not sending HTML entities.

Comment: HTML entities are so 1990s. Nowadays every single computer on the planet understands UTF-8 correctly, so there's no need for them anymore (except for &lt; / &gt; in HTML pages, of course).

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i solved the problem. To convert HTML entity to original string as follows.

1) [download](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser/tree/master/Classes) content.
2) add GTMNSString+HTML.h .m and NSString+html.h .m files to your project.
3) assume your return string is 'allData' then convert it in original string by using
[allData stringByDecodingHTMLEntities] function.

That's it. got your original string!!